# no viable alternative at character ' ' What does this mean?

Tags: apex, developer-console

There is a method in a class which i am trying to call from developer console.
Here is the definition of the class

```
public static void ruleEngine(String rule, Date eventdate, String area, Boolean myPortal, String EventType, String EventId)
```

And here is how i am calling it on Developer console

```
aclass.ruleEngine('Event Consultant', 2012-11-17 00:00:00 , 'St. Louis' , false, 'Wi-Fi', 'a0mC0000000bEJf');
```

and the error message i get is

> line 1, column 79: line 1:79 no viable alternative at character ' '

is it the way i am passing the date?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just try it ? Yes, dates should be written as a string literal.

Comment: ok i tried removing i get this error line 0, column -1: unexpected token: '2012-11-17'

Comment: i actually got it work by passing it as a variable as suggested by salesforce wizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the way of passing the date. You could remove the time (since it's not a datetime) and try that. Or to be really save use a variable:

```
Date MyDate = date.newinstance(2012,11,17);
```

and then pass that into your method

Comment: Or use this:
date mydate = date.parse('12/27/2009');

Comment: @PJC the parser is somehow bound to running user's locale. I had some nasty unit test failures while deploying to production, it worked for one dev but not for another. Turned out that somebody wanted to save himself typing and doing proper Date.newInstance ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes its the way you are passing the date.

You can use this

```
Date eventdate=date.valueOf('2012-11-17 00:00:00');
```

Returns a Date that contains the value of the specified String. The String should use the standard date format “`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`” in the local time zone

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while doing a SOQL query. Since this post appears in search while searching for the error. I will add some more points -

1. **Always check the required data type**, we are used to integers and strings but when it comes to less used datatypes like date, we forget to convert it in the required format.

   > ```
   > dateTime d1 = System.now();      //now() gives only dateTime
   > dateTime d2 = System.today();    //today() gives date or dateTime
   > date d3 = System.today();
   > ```

   *Initializing date and dateTime -*

   > ```
   > //dateTime d4 = dateTime.newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
   > dateTime d4 = dateTime.newInstance(2020,12,30,12,04,34);
   >
   > //date d5 = date.newInstance(year, month, day);
   > date d5 = date.newInstance(2020,12,30);
   > ```

   *Converting from String* - Do care about the format of date

   > ```
   > date d6 = date.parse('12/30/2020');       //MM/DD/YYY format (slash)
   > date d7 = date.valueOf('2020-12-30');     //YYYY-MM-DD format (hyphen)
   > System.debug(d6 == d7);
   > ```
2. **`Date`, `Time` and `DateTime` are all different**, so if you want to compare `dateTime` you should convert the variable into `DateTime` because `date` will throw error. The below code will throw error.

   > ```
   > date d8 = System.now();
   > dateTime d9 = System.now();
   > System.debug(d8 == d9);    //error
   > ```
3. **Converting `date` into `string`**, Interesting thing to note here that after conversion the resultant string value is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

   > ```
   > date d4 = date.parse('12/30/2020');
   > String s1 = String.valueOf(d4);      //converts it into YYYY-MM-DD (hyphen)
   > System.debug(s1 == '2020-12-30');    //returns true
   > System.debug(s1 == '12/30/2020');    //returns false
   > ```